# Run send log data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, send-email, logging

I want to log the sends (Triggered send & mass send). Therefore I created a DE by using the SendLog Template.
But the DE is still empty. We are using "Retain Send Log Data" on every single send. Wich step is missing to get the data?

Thx

Comment: None, actually it should be filled with data once you created the dataextension. There can only be one dataextension that is made from the sendlog template. There cant be multiple dataextensions that act as sendlog. When it is not populating ask salesforce support if there is a misconfiguration.

Comment: You can only have 1 sendlog per BU, if you have one already it may be writing there. Also DO you know if your sendlog is configured at the BU or the ENT level?

Comment: it just needed 3 days until it worked. Don´t ask :-). Thx